# How can I get Destiny for xbox 360 to work with external Hard Drive?

Tags: xbox-360, destiny, hard-drive

My son received a copy of Destiny for Xbox 360 and a 2 TB hard drive for Christmas.

When he tried to play Destiny, it came up with an error, telling us that Destiny required an Xbox 360 hard drive.

We hooked the hard drive up, and installed Destiny to it. When we try to play Destiny, the same error comes up, again.

We have searched online for a solution, and have tried everything we can think of, but nothing fixes the problem

How can we play Destiny?

Comment: What speed is your hard drive? USB 2.0 or USB 3.0?

Comment: What other things did you try? Can you confirm having formated the hard drive to support playing games before you transfered the game over?

Comment: And as a last thought, what exactly do you mean when you initially say "transfer the game over"? Destiny does not require a hard drive to play. It requires the xbox to have the available memory. If you have simply transfered the game without any download directly too the drive, that suggests your Xbox already has the required space (to store the game, in the mean tiime).

Comment: thanks for your reply Timelord64! It is a 3.0. Yes, I did format the hard drive, and other games are working with the hard drive, so the problem is not with the hard drive. It says right on the front of the game "hard drive required" and when we first put the game it, it came up with a notice that said "you must have an xbox 360 hard drive to play destiny". So I pulled the hard drive out of the packaging and plugged it in, but the same notice kept coming up. So I did some research and found that you have to transfer the game over to the external memory. so we did that, but get the same notice.

Comment: we have restarted, deleted, re-installed/updated, unplugged the xbox, and done everything we can think of, and can't find any help online that suggests anything we haven't already done. could it be a problem with the game, and maybe exchanging for a new game would fix it?

Comment: problem resolved. We called the local game shop, and it turns out our xbox 360 did not come with an internal hard drive, and we had to go buy one, and it is now working! how were we supposed to know that the xbox came without a hard drive inside already?!

Answer (score 2):

Destiny lists itself as "requiring an Xbox hard drive" because it requires an **internal Xbox hard drive**. In this particular case, it turned out that your console was the "arcade" variant, which does not come with an internal drive.

Please keep in mind that future releases will eat up more hard drive space.

Along with the core Destiny game, there are currently three DLCs<sup>1</sup>;

- The Dark Below
- The House of Wolves
- The Taken King

The Taken King can be considered more of an expansion, and brought a lot of changes to Destiny. These changes effected the vanilla version, too.

Returning players may find that the same occurrence happens with an update, as game updates are frequent, and can often add or change content.

Players that have an account registered prior to September 15, 2015, [may be entitle to a free memory upgrade](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/destinys-solution-for-ps3xbox-360-hard-drive-size-/1100-6430393/).

By [contacting Bungie through their customer support](https://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Destiny-The-Taken-King-Storage-Solution), players may be entitle to receiving a free USB designed for their Xbox 360 or PlayStation 3, with the latest updates from The Taken King.

<sub><sup>1</sup>At least, as of 6/4/2016.</sub>

Comment: But it says here you can install the game to a USB drive https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/13478

Answer (score -2):

When going to the game on main menu, press x then "install" and then choose your hard drive when prompted

Comment: try to expand your answer, currently it doesn't answer the question since they clearly stated that they did install the software.